# Fitting a regression model

Tags: regression, self-study, linear-model

I'm trying to solve a question from a Chinese "linear statistical models", and the chapter containing this question is about weighted least squares.

The question and the way I solve it are as following:
[image]

As you can see, the predicted values is very different to the actual value, so I wonder about whether I solve it right or not.

Could somebody tell me what is wrong with it? And if there are mistakes how I correct it?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I wouldn't say that the predicted values are "very different" from the actual values at all. In statistics, you can rarely or never hope to be perfectly accurate, just to be accurate enough, or as accurate as possible.

Comment: Why did you put $X_i$ in for the inverse-weights? Take a closer look at the question

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations seem correct, but if you have a look at your data (i.e. plot $Y$ vs $X$), you'll notice that your data are not *perfectly* linear. This explains the small difference between $Y$ and $\hat{Y}$...

Comment: The OP's calculations are wrong.